# ElasticSearch: Inner_hits for nested query under bool - supported?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to get inner hits to work for an 'AND'ed nested queries (using bool-must)

Basically, it's two nested queries under a must, but I only seem to get inner-hits from one branch, even though it's a MUST, so both branches must have hit.

Is this supported?

[this is actually Python code, but it's basically json]

```
{
    'size': 10, 
    'query': {
        'bool': {
            'must': [{
                'nested': {
                    'path': 'attributes', 
                    'score_mode': 
                    'avg', 'inner_hits': {},
                     'query': {'bool': {
                             'must': [{'match': {'attributes.ename': 'n1'}},
                                      {'match': {'attributes.sv': 'v1'}}]}}}}, 
                      {
                 'nested': {
                    'path': 'attributes', 
                    'score_mode': 
                    'avg', 
                    'inner_hits': {},
                    'query': {'bool': {
                            'must': [{'match': {'attributes.ename': 'n2'}},
                                     {'match': {'attributes.sv': 'v2'}}]}}}}]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, your second 'inner_hits' is overwriting the first.  You can give each one a 'name' to make sure that they both return:

```
{
'size': 10, 
'query': {
    'bool': {
        'must': [{
            'nested': {
                'path': 'attributes', 
                'score_mode': 
                'avg', 'inner_hits': {'name': 'first'},
                 'query': {'bool': {
                         'must': [{'match': {'attributes.ename': 'n1'}},
                                  {'match': {'attributes.sv': 'v1'}}]}}}}, 
                  {
             'nested': {
                'path': 'attributes', 
                'score_mode': 
                'avg', 
                'inner_hits': {'name': 'second'},
                'query': {'bool': {
                        'must': [{'match': {'attributes.ename': 'n2'}},
                                 {'match': {'attributes.sv': 'v2'}}]}}}}]
    }
  }
}
```

But an even better approach might be to reduce the whole thing to one nested query with multiple must queries.  Something like:

```
{
  'size': 10, 
  'query': {
    'nested': {
      'path': 'attributes', 
      'score_mode': 'avg', 
      'inner_hits': {},
      'query': {
        'bool': {
          'must': [
            {'match': {'attributes.ename': 'n1'}},
            {'match': {'attributes.ename': 'n2'}},
            {'match': {'attributes.sv': 'v1'}},
            {'match': {'attributes.sv': 'v2'}}
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```